# how i can find com.ibm.ws.exception.wsexception jar file?

Tags: build, websphere

i added the admin.jar file correctly to the classpath and to my java application, but these errors still appear  **1- The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.ibm.ws.exception.WsException. Fix the build path then try building this project.**

**2- The type com.ibm.ws.exception.WsException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required**, i understand that there is a helper jar file should be added to my app, but unfortunetely i could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things here:

1) You need WebSphere classes in your build path.  The server provides an API/SPI jar specifically for this purpose: WAS_HOME/dev/was_public.jar.  It contains WsException, among other classes.

2) You mentioned having "admin.jar" in your class path and Java application.  If that means that you're packaging a WebSphere server jar in your Java EE application... don't do that.  The server jars are not designed to be packaged within apps, and you run a very high risk of unexpected linkages and class loader hierarchy issues if you try it.

If this is a standalone Java client, not a Java EE application installed on the server, there are thin client jars in WAS_HOME/runtimes that are designed to be used in client application class paths; the server jars in the plugins directory are not designed to be used outside the context of the application server itself.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with Jarid that the proper way is by using the client but if you still need it, then you can download it from https://github.com/NURGALIYESMUKHAMEDOV/Utils/blob/master/CaseSchedule/src/main/resources/wsexception.jar where I found it and used it in my library too.

Comment: Don't download and run compiled code from random sources.

Comment: @Khoyo Obviously we should not use any compiled code from untrusted sources. The comment was to help any java client who desperately want to use it. I had used it to development environment for a proof of concept and it worked fine. However Jarid's recommendation remains the proper way to proceed.